# Windows ReactJs scripts build copy 3 files into build folder

Tags: reactjs, windows, batch-file, google-chrome-extension

I'm a Windows user and I'm doing my chrome extension project using react. I have 3 javascript files in the src folder (1 file is the background file, I have two other content scripts). I want to be in the build folder after I run `npm run build`, till now I was copying the files in the build folder each time I was rebuilding the project. Can create a .bat file that copies these 3 files in the build folder?
I've created a `build.bat` file under `scripts` folder inside my project folder.

build.bat:

```
build() {
    echo 'building react...'

    react-scripts build

    copy src/background.js build/background.js
    copy src/getProductInfo.js build/getProductInfo.js
    copy src/getProductReviews.js build/getProductReviews.js
}

build
```

package.json:

```
....

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "start scripts/build.bat",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

....
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That isn't `.bat` file syntax, there's no command in batch files like `build() {`, `}`, or `build`. Your built/resultant `.bat` file should look like this **1.** `@echo 'building react...'`, **2.** `@react-scripts build`, **3.** `@copy src\background.js build`, **4.** `@copy src\getProductInfo.js build`, and **5.** `@copy src\getProductReviews.js build`.

Comment: Thank your for your reply! I knew the syntax was wrong because I copied that content from a .sh file. Anyway, I have ```"build": "start /scripts/build.bat",``` inside package.json file and when I run ```npm run build``` I have this error: ```PS C:\Users\stef_\OneDrive\Desktop\importer> npm run build

> importer@0.1.0 build C:\Users\stef_\OneDrive\Desktop\importer
> start /scripts/build.bat

Invalid switch - "/scripts".```

Comment: How I can run that file whenever I'm running ```npm run build```?

Comment: And I changed the file as you mentioned. Thank you!